# SimplePie RSS - get_language in NULL

Tags: php, rss, feed, simplepie

Hi i use SimplePie in this way:

```
$feed = new SimplePie();
$feed->set_feed_url( array("feed.xml", "feed2.xml") );
$feed->enable_cache(false);
$feed->init();
$feed->handle_content_type();

var_dump($feed->get_language());

foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item):
```

get_language() return NULL .. I miss something?

Is possible get the language of each Item?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The language element is optional in the [RSS specification](http://www.rssboard.org/rss-specification#optionalChannelElements), if it doesn't have one the author didn't supply it. The likelihood is it's `en` when `get_language()` returns `null`, which is probably about the safest assumption you can make.